# Deleting cookies on iOS Simulator for UI testing automation

Tags: ios, cookies, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing some UI tests for iOS application. The app uses SFSafariViewController and this leaves some cookies behind.

I need to delete them to build repeatable tests (which starts from the same state).

It looks like I found that cookies are stored at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<SimulatorID>/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies`

I delete them. However, it looks like Safari caches them in the memory (until Simulator is restarted).

Any ideas how to force Safari to clear the cache?

Comment: Hey, have you ever found a solution to this? :)